# How do I tame a zombie horse?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I tame a zombie horse? I can't find them naturally, but when I spawn them in, I can't ride them... I do already know how to tame a Skellington horse, though.

Answer (score 1):

"Adult horses, donkeys, and mules can be tamed, but not zombie horses or *skeleton horses. With an empty hand mount the horse repeatedly; when it no longer bucks the player and shows hearts, it is tamed. It is necessary to tame a horse in order to breed it, give it equipment, or ride it for any length of time.
Taming depends on the horse's "temper". Horses begin with a temper of 0 out of 100. When a player is riding the horse, a random number 0–99 is chosen. The horse becomes tame if this number is less than the temper, otherwise the temper is increased by 5 and the player is bucked off. Temper can also be increased by feeding the horse.*"

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse

You should however be able to summon a tamed zombie horse by using commands:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3, Tame:1}
```

by typing this in chat and sending it, you should have summoned a zombie horse.

Comment: Oops! The command you have shown is for Java Edition, but this is Bedrock Edition.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I think that the original post I responded to said Java Edition, it seems that it has been edited by others since.  I'm not entirely sure what to think about that... I don't think that Bedrock Edition was actually out when this was asked   /:

Comment: @Jason_ it said PE in the title even in the initial question, but to be fair it was only tagged Java so I think that's fine :), sorry for... "necro-commenting" () but wanted to clear up the brutal fight